# What is the difference between Admin and Domain Admin group?

Tags: active-directory

I'm making security tests and create two users adding them in two difference groups: `Administrator` in Folder `/Builtin` and `Domain Admin` in folder `/Users` and depending on attack, is only possible with Domain Admin permission

Answer (score 0):

Domain Admins (DA) gets most of it's privileges from membership in Administrators. There are also a small number of AD functions that specifically require DA.

DA cannot have members from other domains, so in a multi-domain forest it is typical to had administrator accounts added to Administrators and not DA.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the previous observation that DAs inherit most of their rights via Administrators membership, by default, they also have Local Administrator rights on every computer on the domain (via a GPO that shouldn't be removed). Administrators doesn't, since it's a Builtin Local group.

Administrators are the default Owner of most objects in the AD directory as well as "local admin" on each DC.

[Implementing Least-Privilege Administrative Models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/implementing-least-privilege-administrative-models) is a useful guide from Microsoft as to what basic controls should be enabled on these groups and their members.